# Not getting expected output from log4j when the logs are printed in file

Tags: java, log4j

Problem:
We got 2 logs printed in the file like this:
[image: Difference in time]

Analysis
1)These 2 logs are printed one after the other in the code and here too but the time difference is 7 minutes which is huge.
2)This has been observed when there is only one War file as well as multiple wars in the Tomcat.

Below is the log4j configuration file to analyse the issue clearly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false">

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="callback" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/subs_engine.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}_subs_engine.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="callback" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

> Can anyone guide me how to solve or debug this problem:
>   Is this the problem of log4j?

We are using log4j-1.2.17.jar

@Edit:

```
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_DEBUG, Utility.class.getName(),"Inside loadHttpReqToBean.");
```

Logger class Calling syslog method[image]

Comment: Logging code may help understanding the issue, as well as your log4j configuration.
Do you use asynchronous appender ?

Comment: @BigAleski I have updated the configuration file.

Comment: Should I use Log4j 2 to solve this problem?